# SQL error when UPDATE wrapped in cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below code on its own does exactly as I require.

```
UPDATE [MASKED_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-CUSTOMER325] 
SET    [MASKED_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-CUSTOMER325].[SELL PRICE] = ROUND 
([Orbisrates].[dbo].[ORBIS_IMPORT_JUNE2014].[PEAKPERMINUTE] / 60 * 
[OrbisBilling].[dbo].[MASKED_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-CUSTOMER325].[CHARGEDTIMESECS] + [Orbisrates].[dbo].[ORBIS_IMPORT_JUNE2014].[PEAKCONNECT], 4) 
FROM   [OrbisRates].[dbo].[ORBIS_IMPORT_JUNE2014] 
       INNER JOIN 
       [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[MASKED_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-CUSTOMER325] 
               ON 
       [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[MASKED_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-CUSTOMER325].[TO] 
       LIKE 
       [ORBIS_IMPORT_JUNE2014].[DESTINATION] + '%' 
WHERE 
[OrbisBilling].[dbo].[MASKED_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-CUSTOMER325].[TARIFF LOOKUP] 
= 'Orbis_Import_June2014'
```

The issue is that when I wrap it in a cursor I get an error.

If I place the code into the cursor without any edits, as per the below, I get

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Orbis_Import_June2014'

Code:

```
DECLARE @tablevalue NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX); 

DECLARE table_value_cursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT DISTINCT [Tariff Lookup]
   FROM [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325];

OPEN table_value_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM table_value_cursor INTO @tablevalue 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = N'

    UPDATE [masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325] 
    SET [masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[Sell Price] = 
ROUND ([Orbisrates].[dbo].[Orbis_Import_June2014].[Peakperminute]/60*[OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[ChargedTimeSecs]+[Orbisrates].[dbo].[Orbis_Import_June2014].[Peakconnect],4) 
    FROM [OrbisRates].[dbo].[Orbis_Import_June2014]
    INNER JOIN [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325] on [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[To] LIKE [Orbis_Import_June2014].[Destination]+'%'
    WHERE [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[tariff lookup] = 'Orbis_Import_June2014'';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql; 

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_value_cursor INTO @tablevalue; 
END 

CLOSE table_value_cursor 
DEALLOCATE table_value_cursor;
```

To get rid of this error, I added a couple of quotes to my WHERE statement.

```
WHERE [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[tariff lookup] = ''Orbis_Import_June2014'''
```

However now when I run the code it errors, saying

> The data types nvarchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.

As per some advise in a previous post, I placed my LIKE statement in additional quotes, but to no avail. Same error

```
INNER JOIN [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325] on [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[To] LIKE ''[Orbis_Import_June2014].[Destination]+'%'''
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You also need to change the ON clause ending from " +'%''" to " + ''%'''".

Comment: Hmm! That's hard to read. Essentially, double-up the single quotes again around the wild-card.

Comment: Aside from your syntax problems, which I think Pieter Geerkens is right about, you are not using `@tablevalue` in your code - so the `UPDATE` will run in the same way for as many values as there are in your `CURSOR` population. Also, I would try my hardest to avoid using a `CURSOR` - but until it is clear what `@tablevalue` is for, no one will be able to make any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If data type of [tariff lookup] column is `NVarChar()` Use `N` befor of your value in where condition.

```
WHERE [OrbisBilling].[dbo].[masked_2014-06-30-2014-06-01-customer325].[tariff lookup] = N''Orbis_Import_June2014'''
```